# Specified condition on single selection in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to create a report. My problem comes from the fact that I need to use COUNT(market) for the year to date (total) of each 'market' then I also need a COUNT of 'market' for only the user imputed month ($mon). I cannot find any reference to using a WHERE on only a single selected field, everything else works as intended giving me the market with the percentages and year to date totals.

I need to make the line "COUNT(market) AS Saves" only count markets who's month field equals $mon and everything else to stay as is.

```
SELECT market,
COUNT(market) AS Saves,
COUNT(market) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM savedata2013) * 100 AS Percent,
COUNT(market) AS YTD
FROM savedata2013, ticket_info
GROUP BY market 
ORDER BY COUNT(market) DESC';
```

Example Data:
market - Saves(June) - Percent - YTD
Los Angeles -   530 - 16.5154 - 564
San Jose -  390 - 12.1523 - 415
Irvine   - 371 - 11.5373 - 394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if statement inside a sum, something like...

```
select sum(if(field='$mon',1,0)) as something....
```

I've created a SQLFiddle based on what I think your database might look like, and then run the following query.

So, the DB I used is defined as a market and an enteredDate.  You probably have a lot more information in your ticket_info, but it shouldn't be relevant.

```
create table ticket_info (market varchar(20),
                          enteredDate DateTime);
```

And the query is:

```
SELECT market,
  sum(if(monthname(enteredDate)='June',1,0)) AS `Saves(June)`,
  sum(if(monthname(enteredDate)='June',1,0))/ (SELECT count(*) FROM ticket_info WHERE year(enteredDate) = 2013) AS Percent,
  sum(if(year(enteredDate)=2013,1,0)) AS YTD
FROM ticket_info
GROUP BY market
ORDER BY `Saves(June)` DESC;
```

The percent will be null if there are no tickets entered for the year, but this should be an edge condition.

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce8791/3)

Comment: If I use the following it only returns the same as the total, not just records with month equaling June

    COUNT(if(month=\'June\',market,0)) AS Saves

Comment: Could you give some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: added example output, Saves(June) is a subset of YTD, so there are 564 total Los Angeles tickets for the year, and 530 for Los Angeles for June

Comment: This did not work with my specific data set, as the dates were not in a format parse-able by SQL but it gave me the idea of adding a year column which I can use to remove the complication of . Thank you for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably resolve the problem like this, using CASE statement:

```
SELECT market,
COUNT
(
CASE market
   WHEN month = $mon
      THEN market
      ELSE NULL
END
) AS Saves,
COUNT(market) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM savedata2013) * 100 AS Percent,
COUNT(market) AS YTD
FROM savedata2013, ticket_info
GROUP BY market 
ORDER BY COUNT(market) DESC';
```